# Why does this program terminate when I enter user input?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, macos

The program is supposed to compare a user-inputted string to a text document. If the program finds a match in the file and in part of the string, it should highlight or change the font color of the matching string in what the user inputted. The thing is, once I enter something for user input, the program terminates. Examples of inputs that could have a match in the file are MALEKRQ, MALE, MMALEKR, MMMM, and MALEK. How do I fix this problem? I'm using Eclipse Neon on Mac OS X El Capitan.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ScienceFair 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/Users/Kids/Desktop/ScienceFair/src/MALEKRQsample.txt");
    try 
    {
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Protein Sequence");
        String userProteinSequence = userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        int len = userProteinSequence.length();
        int size = 4;
        int start = 0;
        int indexEnd = size;
        while (indexEnd < len - size) 
        {
            for (int index = start; index <= len - size; index++) 
            {
                String search = userProteinSequence.substring(index, indexEnd);
                System.out.println(search);
                while (fileInput.hasNext()) 
                {
                    String MALEKRQ = fileInput.nextLine();
                    // System.out.println(MALEKRQ);
                    int found = MALEKRQ.indexOf(search);
                    if (found >= 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Yay.");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Fail.");
                    }
                }
                indexEnd++;

            }
            size++;
            if (size > 8) {
                size = 8;
                start++;
            }   
        }
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.err.format("File does not exist.\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the input that you entered?

Comment: @RealSkeptic MALE, which is a protein sequence I've put in the file.

Comment: Is it you want to find all lines that contain the user input, trying successively smaller versions of the input by removing the leading characters so long as there is at least 4 chars of user input being sought?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ScienceFair 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/Users/Kids/Desktop/ScienceFair/src/MALEKRQsample.txt");
    try 
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Protein Sequence");
        String userProteinSequence = userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        for (int size = userProteinSequence.length(); size >= 4; size--) {
            for (int start = 0; start <= userProteinSequence.length()-size; start++) {
                boolean found = false;
                String search = userProteinSequence.substring(start, size);
                System.out.println(search);

                Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
                while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
                    String MALEKRQ = fileInput.nextLine();
                    int found = MALEKRQ.indexOf(search);
                    if (found >= 0) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    System.out.println(search+" found (index "+start+")");
                    fileInput = new Scanner(file);
                    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
                        String MALEKRQ = fileInput.nextLine();
                        MALEKRQ = MALEKRQ.replaceAll(search, "[["+search+"]]");
                        System.out.println(MALEKRQ);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        } 

    System.out.println(search+" not found");
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
        String MALEKRQ = fileInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println(MALEKRQ);
    }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.format("File does not exist.\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the above explanation. The program did return something after entering more than 8 characters. Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I rewrote your program to do the search. I assume that you are searching substrings of any length, including only 1 character.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I took so long to get back to you. I never got a notification. The user can input any number of characters over 4. The lowest number of characters the file has is 4  and the max is 8. I also want the program to show which index of the user input matches the file.

Comment: I modified the program, to search only substrings of length 4 or greater. Also, the program print the index of the user input that matches.

Comment: Thank you. However, when the user needs to input a longer string (say, 100 characters), it needs to match the longest instance of something in the file. Also, at the end of each run, the program prints out each character of the string going until the end.

Comment: This is what I get when using your code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6gwCsgEBqLTQnRPMHFhTVAtVTA/view?usp=sharing I would show you what would happen with a user entering a 100-character string, but that just takes hours of scrolling.

Comment: This program should act like a "Find" function in Notepad, TextEdit, or any web browser. When it finds a particular character, it should highlight where it is. Same thing here. It should give index/highlight/change font color/etc. of the USER-entered string.

Comment: I can't put an entire and complex program in a small post. That requeriments are part of a more complex software. I already resolved the question: "Why does this program terminate when I enter user input?", and provides you with an algorithm that resolves the search part of your software. But I can't resolve the User Interface part, with only a small code to start with, without any other information of the context. It's a web program? It's a desktop program? Use Java Swing, AWT, or any other technology? I recomend to solve other parts posting other questions.

Comment: The program is written on desktop Mac OS X using Eclipse IDE. Swing and AWT are not being used. As for the user interface, there are no windows to build. This is all being done from the console. Thank you for resolving the primary question of why the program terminates and for all your help. I am only a novice at java, and you seem to be extremely fluent in it. Could I please request your help?

Comment: I think you can't highlight words, at least with background or color, in a terminal. But I don't know anything about Mac OS X, and maybe it's possible... I will modify the code, to print the file content, with marks that "highlight" the search result. It's the only help I can provide right now.